# Mouse over effect does not disappear even if the cursor is moved away

Tags: css

[image]

I'm trying to apply bootstrap template. There is an issue about mouse hover effect.

If I click some elements that have `href` attribute, the hover effect does not disappear until I click somewhere again.

How to I make the effect disappear after clicking and move cursor away?

```
a {
  color: #212529;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

a:focus, a:hover {
  color: #0085A1;
}
```

Comment: When you click an `<a>`, it receives a `focus` and it will not lose it unless you click elsewhere. Remove the `a:focus` rule, it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you click a link" the `focus` style will stick since this is the element that is let's say "Selected" by your cursor, simply remove the `a:focus` from the styling.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking off the a:focus off it?

Just do:

```
a:hover {
  color: #0085A1;
}
```

I think its because when you hover on it, it gives focus to that button, so it stays that color.